Selenium instagram like button click
Im trying to click on like button when its not like but im having troubles with actually clicking it. this peace of code used to work fine but now it doesnt. Can you tell me why and how to fix it
<div class="x1i10hfl x972fbf xcfux6l x1qhh985 xm0m39n x9f619 xe8uvvx xdj266r x11i5rnm xat24cr x1mh8g0r x16tdsg8 x1hl2dhg xggy1nq x1a2a7pz x6s0dn4 xjbqb8w x1ejq31n xd10rxx x1sy0etr x17r0tee x1ypdohk x78zum5 xl56j7k x1y1aw1k x1sxyh0 xwib8y2 xurb0ha xcdnw81" role="button" tabindex="0"><div class="x6s0dn4 x78zum5 xdt5ytf xl56j7k">
 <span class="">
   <svg aria-label="Like" class="x1lliihq x1n2onr6 xyb1xck" fill="currentColor" height="24" role="img" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24">
    <title>Like</title>
   </svg>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>

liked=check_exists_by_xpath("//*[@aria-label='Like'][@height='24']", driver, By.XPATH)
 if liked:
        svg_element=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//svg[@aria-label='Like'][@height='24']")
        svg_element.click()

i tried with clicking parent div also but with no success
liked=check_exists_by_xpath("//*[@aria-label='Like'][@height='24']", driver, By.XPATH)
 if liked:
        svg_element=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//svg[@aria-label='Like'][@height='24']")
        svg_element.click()


better show minimal reproducible example which we could copy and run.

sometimes portals changes code in HTML and it needs to change Python code. Some portals can detect selenium and block access or send different content - like Captcha. So maybe first check what HTML you get from server. driver.page_source
